# Does a boxspring offer advantages over slats?

Tags: sleep

Does a boxspring under a mattress offer advantages over flexible slats? I can imagine a boxspring might seem more luxurious since it feels more soft, but that doesn't mean that it supports your body better while sleeping. Also, I would expect boxsprings to be more prone to wear than slats.

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) We want to focus our attention on doubtful claims that are widely held or are made by notable people.  Please [provide some references](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/882/what-are-the-attributes-of-a-good-question/883#883) to places where this claim is being made.